# Decrease indent in Microsoft Word produces blank box?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am having an odd issue in Microsoft Word 2013. I am trying to decrease the indent on the following:
[image]

I click on the 'decrease indent' button on the toolbar [image], so that the bullet point can read 3.1. When I click it, the button area becomes on the following:
[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried restarting Word but the same issue occurs. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list number style set if you haven't already. To do this, here's a link to everything you need to know about creating multilevel lists:
http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/word-2007-taming-multilevel-list-numbering/